# How to slow down replay in Arena

Tags: computer-chess

I am using arena to play through pgn games.
Unfortunately the replay feature is far to fast for me.
I have tried to slow it down by changing the settings in levels but this does not work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Email the Arena support.